# How to get a child's components DOMNode in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

What is the current way to get a DOMNode in ReactJS from a child's component ?

```
...
this.refs.component.getDOMNode() // do not work anymore
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.component) // do also not work anymore
...
```

When access `this.refs.component` I just get the Component back but I need the rendered `DOMNode`. This `DOMNode` is needed by me for example to get the `scrollTop` value of the Element. These values are not available in the Component at it selfs in `this.refs.component`.

**Edit/Answer**

Someone posted an answer which was correct but - I dont know why - he/she deleted the post.

So the correct answer is to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode();

Reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

This works perfectly for my usecase.

Comment: Have you tried ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.component)

Comment: According to the [Change Log](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d1a003ee72f2cd91574cc2a76fb72190850eacbc/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Change Log](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d1a003ee72f2cd91574cc2a76fb72190850eacbc/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations)

> this.getDOMNode() is now deprecated and ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) can
>   be used instead. Note that in the common case, findDOMNode is now
>   unnecessary since a ref to the DOM component is now the actual DOM
>   node.

The `this.refs.component.getDOMNode()` is no longer to use anymore. You can use **ReactDOM**.findDOMNode(this.refs.component) as what I mentioned in the comments instead.